# Cannot find an existing dependency when running a python module from Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask, virtualenv

I have a python module, it works fine, it uses pandas as one of its dependencies.

I added a Flask application in the middle with a rest service which has a service that imports and runs the very same module.

```
module = importlib.import_module('modules.' + script.module, package=__package__)
```

Both the python module and the flask app run with the same virtualenv activated, in which pandas is installed.

-BUT- when running this through the flask app, it throws an exception:

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Tried to run the module without calling it from Flask and it works just fine...

**=== UPDATE ===**

I don't know why Flask is running on python 2 even though I'm running it with a virtualenv of python 3 activated.

This is the script I'm using to start my Flask app:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=run.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

I'd appreciate any help

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it.
I haven't installed Flask within the virtualenv I was running, so I think that's why Flask was running on a different python version. 
So I installed flask on my virtualenv and now it works.